# How to rebuild Widget after replaced Route gets popped?

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

I basically have one MainScreen with a list of items. If I click one of these items I the user gets routed to the DetailScreen. From the DetailScreen he can either go to the next item, or back to the MainScreen:

```
MainScreen -> DetailScreen(0) -> DetailScreen(1) -> MainScreen
```

In MainScreen I use `Navigator.pushNamed()`
In DetailScreen I use `Navigator.replaceRoute()`

I need the MainScreen to rebuild after i leave the last DetailScreen.
`Navigator.pushNamed().then(((_) => setState(() {})))` gets already called after DetailScreen(0) gets replaced.

Passing a callback to DetailScreen might work, but doesn't seem very elegant. Is there a better way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

If by not elegant you mean asynchronous, then you can definitely do this:
In your function(For ex: onTap function)

```
ListTile(
  //Other Properties
  onTap: () async {
    var value = await Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/myroutename");
    setState(() {});
  }
)
```